# Apache virtual host configuration error

Tags: configuration, apache2, virtualhost, django

I'm trying to configure Apache2 with Django and mod_wsgi on a virtual host.

I wrote a simple configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost: *.80>

        ServerName gpx
        ServerAlias gpx.gpsfte
        DocumentRoot /var/www/gpx/htdocs

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/django/gpx/wsgi/mainapp.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

But when I reload Apache I get this error:

```
# service apache2 reload
apache2: Syntax error on line 237 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gpx: Expected </VirtualHost:> but saw </VirtualHost>
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

I'm really lost, what does it mean with `</VirtualHost:>`?
Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Which line is 237 in your apache2.conf?

Comment: copy paste the code in vim editor may missing <virtualhost >tag check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem looks like it is with the way you've opened the section: the ending tag that matches `<VirtualHost: ...>` is `</VirtualHost:>`, as the error indicates.

Presumably you meant to open the section with the following instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

(note that there is no colon after `VirtualHost`)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a web server, your current structure and configuration would look more like this:

```
<VirtualHost: *:80>
      ServerName       domain.tld
      ServerAlias      sub.domain.tld
      DocumentRoot     /path/to/document/root
      WSGIScriptAlias  /var/django/gpx/wsgi/mainapp.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```